# Font Awesome macros not displaying correct symbols in math mode

Tags: math-mode, align, fontawesome

Just wondering if anyone knows why the symbols from the `fontawesome` package do not show up correctly here (in the underbrace). For example the Twitter logo works fine when not in the align part, but inside it does not work. I have tried using `\text{\faTwitter}` but this also does not work. Note that this is just a small section from a larger align stream of equations.

.[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\faTwitter

\begin{align*}
\text{(this)} &= E \cdot e^{-r(T-t)} \cdot \Phi'\left[d(S,t) - \sigma \sqrt{T-t}\right] \cdot \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \Bigg[ d(S,t) - \sigma \sqrt{T-t} \Bigg]}_{\faTwitter}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\text{\faTwitter}` works (-;

Comment: Thank you @ebo I must have made a typo when trying this before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the math mode with `\text{}` to use `fontawesome` macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \faTwitter
    \begin{align*}
        \text{\faTwitter} &= E \cdot e^{-r(T-t)} \cdot \Phi'\left[d(S,t) - \sigma \sqrt{T-t}\right] \cdot \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \Bigg[ d(S,t) - \sigma \sqrt{T-t} \Bigg]}_{\text{\faTwitter}}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```